# Using this Git Bash code still cannot enter text and push file to GitHub repository

Tags: git, bash

I am entering the following Git Bash commands into its prompt but still cannot add text to the file and push it to my remote GitHub repository.

```
vim HelloWorld.md  
## This is a markdown file  
git add HelloWorld.md  
https://github.com/myusername/nameofmyremotegithubrepository
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think you should have an access token from the github. Check this out https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: Is the issue that you can't update the file locally, or that you can't push it to the remote, or both?

Comment: Are there any other commands you have executed?
Did you commit your changes?

Comment: Have you executed `git commit` and `git push` command.?

Comment: Hi Tim B. Thanks for your help. janice4928.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloned a github repository, make your changes, add the files (`git add <file>`), commit (`git commit -m "<commit message>"`), and then push with `git push origin <branch>`

If you haven't cloned but you have created an empty github repository (https://github.com/myusername/nameofmyremotegithubrepository):

1. create a folder for your repo on your file system
2. cd to the folder
3. `git init`
4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/nameofmyremotegithubrepository`
5. make your changes
6. add the files (`git add <file>`),
7. commit (`git commit -m "<commit message>"`),
8. and then push with `git push origin <branch>`

Comment: Hi pedrorijo91. Thanks for your very comprehensive and helpful reply. janice4928

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
vim ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pup
```

copy the generated string if you couldn't find this file try to generate ssh public key [Generating SSH Public key](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-2-generate-a-new-ssh-key)

make sure to add this public key to github.